# Rotating image like in standard feature ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, rotation, transformation

How can I rotate an image similar to how it's done in the standard gallery feature? The standard gallery has wheel which the user can tap with one finger and swipe from left to right and turn image to 45 degrees. 
Here a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code for rotation.

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)(angel));

self.imageView.transform = newTransform;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for rotation.

```
CGFloat degrees = 45.0f; //the value in degrees
CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI/180;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need single finger rotate.

Here is library you can go with:

https://github.com/zedoul/ZDStickerView